# Android onClickListener not firing for child views

Tags: android, onclick, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I am developing an app that is using onClickListeners to flip over tiles.  I have the whole thing in a RelativeLayout.  I then have a second RelativeLayout to contain all of my tiles for easy clearing and adding.  I also have various other buttons predefined in the xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/boardlayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/skill2Button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In code, I add Tiles, which are ImageViews with my custom actions. I also add onClickListeners to them. The grid variable is my mainlayout RelativeLayout shown above.

```
private void createTiles(){
    //Create the tiles
    int j = 0;
    Tile t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){

        int r = i/5;
        int c = j%5;
        t = new Tile(this, r, c);
        t.setOnClickListener(tileClicked);

        j++;
        if(j == 5)
            j=0;            

        grid.addView(t);
    }
}
```

The problem is with the older Android versions, these tiles never seem to get the click event fired.  I added onClickListeners to the tiles, and then one on the RelativeLayout just to test and the RelativeLayout gets the event, but the tiles do not.

The menu ImageView (shown in the xml above) has an onClickListener as well, and it gets fired.

In newer Android versions, this works fine.  This makes me wonder if the older versions have an issue with passing down the events from views added in code.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong for the older versions?

Comment: Maybe try `setOnTouchListener()` or the `android:clickable="true"` property.  Other than that, it seems like what you have should work properly.

Comment: I tried both of those and many combinations of different things, no luck.  I have exhausted everything I can think of.  It is driving me nuts.

Comment: @Xather Did you ever solve your issue?  I am having similar problems...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void createTiles(){
    //Create the tiles
    int j = 0;
    Tile t[30];

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){

        int r = i/5;
        int c = j%5;
        t = new Tile(this, r, c);
        t[i].setOnClickListener(this);

        j++;
        if(j == 5)
            j=0;            

        grid.addView(t);
    }
}
```

You need to implement OnClickListener in your class.
Then you have to override onClick method as :

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

          case // switch the ids of your views by calling getId method on them           
        }
    }
```